# Combining two methods together

Tags: c++, c, function, opengl

The following two functions calculate the body force for an objects of type obj. The first function calls the second one twice, is there any way to combine these to methods together?

```
void calculateBodyForcesForEach(obj *pBody, obj *pHead, sys *sys) {
    float fTotalForce[4] = {0.0f};

     calculateBodyForces(pBody, sys->m_pSun, fTotalForce, sys);


     for (obj *pOtherBody = pHead; pOtherBody;) {       
         if (pBody != pOtherBody) {
             calculateBodyForces(pBody, pOtherBody, fTotalForce, sys);
         }
         pOtherBody = pOtherBody->m_pNext;
     }  

     vecCopy(fTotalForce, pBody->m_fForce);
}

void calculateBodyForces(obj *pBody, obj *pOtherBody, 
                         float *fTotalForce, solarSystem *sys) 
{
    pBody->m_fForce[0] = 0.0f;
    pBody->m_fForce[1] = 0.0f;
    pBody->m_fForce[2] = 0.0f;

    float fCalculatedForce[3] = {0.0f};

    float fCalculatedMass = pBody->m_fMass * pOtherBody->m_fMass;

    float fDistanceBetweenPos[3] = {0.0f};
    vecSub(pOtherBody->m_fPosition, pBody->m_fPosition, fDistanceBetweenPos);

    float fDistanceSquared = (fDistanceBetweenPos[0] * fDistanceBetweenPos[0]) + (fDistanceBetweenPos[1] * fDistanceBetweenPos[1]) + (fDistanceBetweenPos[2] * fDistanceBetweenPos[2]);         

    float fUnitVector[3] = {0.0f};
    vecSub(pOtherBody->m_fPosition, pBody->m_fPosition, fUnitVector);
    vecNormalise(fUnitVector, fUnitVector);

    float fGravitationalForce = sys->m_fGravitationalConstant * (fCalculatedMass / fDistanceSquared);

    vecScalarProduct(fUnitVector, fGravitationalForce, fCalculatedForce);

    vecAdd(fTotalForce, fCalculatedForce, fTotalForce); 
}
```

//////My solution so far but still its not working

```
void calculateVelocityAndPosition(planet *pElement, solarSystem *pSystem) { //completly modified  

    float fStartPosition[4] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
    float fAccelerationTime[3] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
    float fVelocityInterval[3] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
    float fTotalCalculated[3] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
    vecCopy(pElement->m_fPosition, fStartPosition);
    vecScalarProduct(pElement->m_fAcceleration, pSystem->m_fTimeStep * pSystem->m_fTimeStep, fAccelerationTime);
    vecScalarProduct(fAccelerationTime, 0.5f, fAccelerationTime);
    vecScalarProduct(pElement->m_fVelocity, pSystem->m_fTimeStep, fVelocityInterval);
    vecAdd(fVelocityInterval, fAccelerationTime, fTotalCalculated);
    vecAdd(fStartPosition, fTotalCalculated, pElement->m_fPosition);
    fori(3){
    pElement->m_fVelocity[i] = (pElement->m_fPosition[i] - fStartPosition[i]) / pSystem->m_fTimeStep;
    }
    fori(3)
     if (pElement->m_fVelocity[i] > pSystem->m_fMaxVelocity)
     pElement->m_fVelocity[i] = pSystem->m_fMaxVelocity;
     else if (pElement->m_fVelocity[i] < pSystem->m_fMaxNegativeVelocity)
     pElement->m_fVelocity[i] = pSystem->m_fMaxNegativeVelocity;
    vecScalarProduct(pElement->m_fVelocity, pSystem->m_fDragCoefficient, pElement->m_fVelocity);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `combine`? If reqd, you can use the inner function code in the first function loop itself but what is exactly your query?

Comment: to make the body of the two functions in one functions body

Comment: any reason you cannot `cut-paste` the code inside the loop, as mentioned in my earlier comment?

Comment: the function is called twice inside the first one, so if i copy and past i will paste the second function twice which something i am trying not to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
fori(3)
```

What does it mean?

This sum:

```
float fDistanceSquared = (fDistanceBetweenPos[0] * fDistanceBetweenPos[0]) + (fDistanceBetweenPos[1] * fDistanceBetweenPos[1]) + (fDistanceBetweenPos[2] * fDistanceBetweenPos[2]);
```

better make a loop out of it:

```
float fDistanceSquared = 0.0f
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
 fDistanceSquared += fDistanceBetweenPos[i] * fDistanceBetweenPos[i];
```

How do you determine the scalar product? Why are there three variables in it?
Also, could be helpful to know the problem being solved.